# Syntax to Reference Pandas Dataframe Columns using Enums

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame object.  I've created an Enum which I use to validate the quality of the imported CSV, and to reference the columns elsewhere in the application.  A sample is below:

```py
class FooProps(Enum):
    FOO = 'Foo'
    BAR = 'Bar Bar'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

data = ds.getFooProperties() # Imports CSV, Validates headers match enum

# Executes operation across Dataframe

someBigNumber = 10000
spam = someBigNumber/ data[str(FooProps.BAR)]
```

I'm new to Python, but it seems counterintuitive that I need to reference the column by self-casting the enum as a string.  Is there a more natural way to build the class such that I can index the columns by Class.Property without the extra syntax of invoking the cast?  For example: `spam = someBigNumber/ data[FooProps.BAR]`

I thought about building an Abstract Class, but from what I understand those don't exist... only abstract methods, which don't really meet the requirement.

I also thought about making it a regular class, but then I have to declare an instance of that class and that also seems wrong.

Comment: You can use `FooProps.BAR.value` to access the enum value. Not the most convenient for sure.

Comment: That seems like an equal workaround with `str(FooProps.BAR)` though I guess I get better intellisense support with the .value notation.